# Como colocar informações de um banco em um campo select no PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho uma página que conecta no banco e traz informações corretamente, no entanto, gostaria de colocar estar informações em um formulário usando o campo select, mas estou tendo algumas dificuldades se alguém puder me ajudar segue meu código.

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';

// abre a conexão
$PDO = db_connect();

// SQL para selecionar os registros
$sql = "SELECT cliente FROM clientes";

// seleciona os registros
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lab</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lab</h1>

    <?php while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <?php echo $user['cliente'] ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer um `select` com seus dados:

```
<select>
  <?php while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $user['cliente'] ?>">
        <?php echo $user['cliente'] ?>
      </option>
  <?php }  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou certinho no entanto faltou na abrir na primeira linha o  {

Comment: Verdade, vou editar aqui.

Answer (score -2):

```
<select>
<?php 
    while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="'.$user['cliente'].'">'.$user['cliente'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```